# How can I add a new property to a list of JSONs based on another list in react using function components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Bit of a JavaScript/react newbie.

Just a bit stuck at the moment on the basic react/JavaScript syntax
this is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from "react";

const testCombineApi = () => {
    const [assocs, setAssocs] = useState([])
    const [loadingData, setLoadingData] = useState([])
    const [corenodes, setCoreNodes] = useState([])

    const projectId = 1
    
    /// i can probably combine both calls? with another then?
    useEffect(() => {
        async function getData() {
            await axios
            .get(`/api/.../`)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data);
                setCoreNodes(response.data)
                setLoadingData(false);
            });
        }
        if (loadingData) {
            getData();
        }
        }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
        await axios
        .get(`/api/.../${projectId}/`)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);
            setAssocs(response.data)
            setLoadingData(false);
        });
    }
    if (loadingData) {
        getData();
    }
    }, []);

    // Trying to add the property "withproject" to every json in the list corenodes
    const initnodes = setCoreNodes({
        ...corenodes, 
        withproject: false
    })

    //this is the part i just to combine the two pieces of info
    // i usually use python, so what i want to do would be 
    // for node in nodes:
    //     node.withproject = True

    // for assoc in assocs:
    //     targetId = assoc.id
    //     for node in nodes:
    //         if targetId = node.id:
    //             node.withproject = False
  
    const testing123 = assocs =>  {
        initnodes
        for (let i=0; i < assocs.length; i++) {
            let id = assocs[i].id
            for (let j = 0; j < corenodes.length; j++) {
                let nodeId = corenodes[j].id  
                {id == nodeId &&
                 setCoreNodes({...corenodes, [corenodes[j].withproject]: false})   
                }
            }

        }
        console.log(corenodes)
    }

    return(
        <ul> {testing123(assocs)} </ul>
    )
    }
    export default testCombineApi
```

I have included my code in the comments as python as to what i'm trying to achieve.
but I'll put it here too for legibility

```
for node in nodes:
    node.withproject = True

for assoc in assocs:
    targetId = assoc.id
    for node in nodes:
        if targetId = node.id:
            node.withproject = False
```

I'm trying to add an additional column that would eventually be rendered as a checkbox in a table which I can then use to then update my DB via an API

This is what a node JSON look like

```
[
    {
        "id": 263,
        "hostname": "qwer123",
        "serial": "",
    },
    {
        "id": 264,
        "hostname": "asdf123",
        "serial": "",
    },
]
```

and I get basically the same thing when I query the API with the specific {$projectID}

is this a reasonable thing to do in react? or I have to rejig the way I'm thinking to get it working??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so let's change the perspective a bit! The "response.data" is not a JSON, it's a collection (list) of JS objects. In JS you have a function that loops trough the whole collection, allowing you to use an arrow function to transform the objects.

In your case:

```
const initnodes = setCoreNodes({
        ...corenodes, 
        withproject: false
    })
```

Could be changed to:

```
const coreNodeModels = corenodes
.map(coreNode => {
    
    // this will create a new object 
    return { 
       withProject: false,
       ...coreNode // this will copy all properties from the coreNode object
    }
})
```

After this you'll have a collection of coreNodeModel's which are a different type than the coreNode's, so store them in a different "useState" state.

I hope I helped, also check out typescript, it's a lot easier to understand at first, and it won't let you confuse types with each other.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you Bence for this, this cleared it up, will try this later!!